# German in Bach's Cantatas

Tags: history, lyrics

My German is very rudimentary (A1) and I have no regular exposure to the language except what I get listening to Bach. Recently, I have been very interested in Bach's cantatas. It uses text from the Luther Bible, I think. I am in the habit of looking at the text with translation as I listen. I'm curious about the German that Bach used and how it compares to modern everyday German. Is it good learning material for me?

Comment: I don't know the text of the Bach cantatas by heart. It would be helpful to provide a link.

Comment: Consider the reverse situation: Would you recommend somebody to learn English using passages from the King James Bible? (To make things worse: Your translation may not be a literal translation of the German text, but just another Bible translation – and those can be very different.)

Comment: Example: http://www.bach-cantatas.com/Texts/BWV7-Eng3P.htm

Comment: Many of Bach's lyrics are even older, because they are literally taken from the Luther Bible translation dated 1545 that would have been "antique German" already in Bach's lifetime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bach used a German spoken at his time (1685-1750) which is considered as *Neuhochdeutsch* but it is not spoken any more today. Nevertheless it is still understood.

In addition to this a lot of changes to grammar and spelling were done for rhyming so that stanzas fit to the melody.

Example:

> O **Haupt** voll Blut und Wunden,
>   voll Schmerz und voller Hohn,
>   o Haupt, zu Spott gebunden
>   mit einer **Dornenkron**,
>   o Haupt, sonst schön **gezieret**
>   mit höchster **Ehr** und **Zier**,
>   jetzt aber hoch **schimpfieret**,
>   gegrüßet seist du mir.
>   <sup>Matthäuspassion BWV 244</sup>

In this short choral we can already see many such expressions (modern German in brackets):

> **Haupt** (Kopf) **Dornenkron** (Dornenkrone) **gezieret** (verziert) **Ehr** (Ehre) **Zier** (Zierde) **hoch** (sehr) **schimpfieret** (verspottet)

This makes me believe that we should not try to learn contemporary German from listening to Bach but listening to (or actively performing) Bach's cantatas may help learning pronunciation, which has not changed so much. He also created and used many idioms that are still valid  today. These may be much better memorized when having a melody to them.

Enjoy Bach for his music, try to understand the vocals using a dictionary, but do not learn to speak this language as propably native Germans will not really get your point.

Just imagine somebody speaking like Shakespeare whose language is comparably off contemporary English as Bach's is from modern German.

Comment: Danke sehr. This is helpful. I will continue listening (I have over a thousand pieces) but will not expect to make a lot of progress learning the language from Bach alone.

Comment: @user137017: added a word on pronuciation which can be learned indeed.

Comment: I agree, by and large, with one exception: Haupt is still used besides Kopf, even if it's no longer the standard term for "head"; it's of somewhat higher register today. And of course there's the secondary meaning Haupt-... (main).

Answer (score 4):

Religious verses in a language of around 1750. This language will hardly help you to read a novel,  newspapers or to understand everday German.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an unusual way to learn German. Basically, you will become an "idiot-savant" in the language. As a "Bachkennner," und "Bibelkenner," you would be very "savvy" in a small, specialized part of the language, and ignorant of the rest of it.

Still, there are some consolations. By studying these, or similarly limited compositions, you will get to an "advanced" level, say B-2 (high intermediate), in which you would be showing "flashes" of expertise, in a small part of the language. This won't translate one-for-one to the rest of the language as a whole, but the vocabulary you acquire may give you the raw material to rise from A1 (rank beginner) to A2 (advanced beginner).