# Verb in third position not followed by adverb

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage, lyrics

I was studying some of Bach's chorals and I came across this title:

> Ach Gott, vom Himmel sieh' darein

According to the grammar rule: after the name, follows the verb, and then everything else, i.e. it should be:

> Ach Gott, sieh' vom Himmel darein

What is the difference? Is there something else I'm not getting here?

Comment: Bachs choral texts are far from todays German - see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11309/1696) - and have to be considered as verses where word order is handled quite freely. No, there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 10):

First, the address *ach Gott* is not part of the sentence. This can easily be seen from the following examples, where an address has been prepended to the major sentence types of German.

> Hans, **hast** du einen Augenblick Zeit? *(yes-no question)*
>   Hans, wann **hast** du denn Zeit? *(wh-question)*
>   Hans, ich **wollte** dich etwas fragen. *(declarative sentence)*

Second, although the imperative is commonly taught, at least to beginners, to have the verb in first position, German actually allows the verb to be in second position in imperatives as well.

> **Komm** jetzt her! *(V1)*
>   Jetzt **komm** her! *(V2)*

*Sieh'* being the imperative of *sehen* and *ach Gott* being an address, the sentence in question is an ordinary imperative with the verb in second position.

Comment: "German actually allows the verb to be in second position in imperatives as well." And poetry uses it to the full - especially if it's a song text, which additionally has to comply with music.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you "are not getting here" is the commented fact that this sentence is part of verses. A text that has to fit into a greater frame with contraints on rhythm and lenght and pronounciation.

That means, the author is quite free in arranging & writing words and might stick less to grammar & spelling - only so much that the text can be understood by (targeted) audience. (sometimes authors don't care).

Second part might come with [linked question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11309/36160): nowadays it is considered old German.

In conclusion: This sentence is just fine for its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *vom Himmel* is an adjunct/adverbial phrase, specifying a location in this case. These are generally flexible with regards to their position in the sentence, and don't affect the relationship between subject/verb/object.

David's answer shows another example, with *jetzt* being an adverb of time. You could combine the two (and more!) to come up with something like

> Ach Gott, vom Himmel jetzt gütlich sieh' auf uns herab!

It is also true that this sounds a bit antiquated and 'poetic', but there is nothing wrong with it from a grammatical perspective.

Comment: This is an interesting point. I would argue that despite their flexibility in declarative clauses, PP adjuncts are not well-fomed in a preverbal slot prefacing an imperative regardless of their semantics.

Comment: @Nico So you would argue _Jetzt komm' her!_ is not grammatically correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread your comment there. How about _Im Dunkeln fahr' aber nicht ohne Licht!_ (I'd say _Zu Hause bleibst du heute_ is not an imperative but a declarative (though pragmatically imperative)).

Comment: "Zu Hause bleibst du heute!", in the sense of a command (you should stay at home)-which to me is ill-formed- would definitely be an imperative. You can also use it in a constative sense, but then in correlation with questions "achso, zu Hause bleibst du heute, anstatt zur Arbeit zu gehen?". The example you quote is good. Then we should go further and look at the semantics of the PPs that are acceptable with imperatives in a preposed slot.

Comment: The verb form _bleibst_ is not an imperative, but 2nd Sg -- that would be _bleib(e)_, as in _Bleib' heute zuhause_. I agree that _Zu Hause bleib' heute_ sounds weird, but I wouldn't go as far as calling it ungrammatical.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I merged the illocutionary force with the morphological encoding. I was multitasking... But nevertheless it would be interesting to pursue the issue as for" the semantics of the PPs that are acceptable with imperatives in a preposed slot". Maybe these PPs are mainly temporal ones ...?