# "Welt, ade, ich bin dein müde" in Bach BWV 158

Tags: lyrics, possessive-pronoun

This question concerns the word *dein* as occurring in a Bach's cantata *Der Friede sei mit dir* (BWV 158) as below.

> Welt, ade, ich bin **dein** müde,
> Salems Hütten stehn mir an,
>   Welt, ade! ich bin dein müde,
>   Ich will nach dem Himmel zu,
> Wo ich Gott in Ruh und Friede
> Ewig selig schauen kann.

The full text you can read [at Emmanuel Music](https://www.emmanuelmusic.org/bach-translations/bwv-158).

You can also hear it [as performed by Dietrich Fischer-Dieskau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FERrn4smBU).

---

**QUESTION**

Should that perhaps be:

> Welt, ade, ich bin dein**er** müde

**BACKGROUND**

The form of the sentence may be the same as that of:

> Ach ich bin des Treibens müde!

which, by the way, is from Goethe's *Wandrers Nachtlied* according to [this Web page](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Nouns/genitive.html).

Emmanuel Music translates the line as:

> World, farewell, I am tired of you

The two items above suggest that *müde* takes a genitive object and *dein* is trying to be a genitive case pronoun for *Welt*.

For a feminine noun, however, that would be *deiner* according to [this formerly Canoo.net page](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/Posses/index.html) or [this Lingolia page](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/pronouns/possessive-pronouns).  Using Lingolia's terminology, I would have said *deiner* so used was an independent possessive pronoun.

The only other reading I can imagine is:

> World, adieu, I am your tired person.

which might go something like:

> Welt, ade, ich bin dein Müden

Does the original Bach line fit either one of these models?  Or is there some third model I should use?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11309/1696) concerning German in Bachs works.

Comment: Wiktionary lists *dein* as an obsolete genitive form of *du*, see the infection table [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/du#Pronoun_6).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an archaism. The genitive pronoun form used to be «dein» (similarly, also «mein»). The form «deiner» (and «meiner») had become common by the 18th century, while Luther in the 16th century still used «dein» and «mein» almost exclusively, cf. [du – DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=du) (scroll down to *«Die nebenform* deiner *für dein»).* The old short form mainly persisted after verbs like *gedenken.*

Answer (score 2):

Best explanation is *deiner* being truncated to *dein*. This is confirmed by the booklet of my recording of the cantata (haenssler classics, directed by Helmut Rilling), which has a full English translation (by Alison Dobson-Ottmes, Dr. Miguel Carazo & Associates) of the sung text:

```
 World, farewell, of thee I’m weary, 
 Salem’s shelter I prefer, 
 World, farewell, of thee I’m weary, 
 I would now to heaven go, 
 Where I God in peace and quiet
 Ever blessed can behold.  
 Where will be a peace most tranquil 
 And eternal grand repose.
```

Since there are further matches of *dein müde* in contemporary literature, see [Google books (blackletter)](https://books.google.de/books?id=3GZFAAAAcAAJ&dq=dein%20m%C3%BCde&hl=de&pg=PR19#v=onepage&q=dein%20m%C3%BCde&f=false), it seems either to be a common truncation or even have been considered as correct at Bach's time.

Another example (also Google books match), where one would expect genitive today:

> O Jesu süß, wer dein gedenkt

Comment: As @mach correctly noted, "dein" is not a "truncation" of "deiner". "Deiner" is an expansion of "dein".